# can't find /etc/hostconfig file on OS X 10.10.3

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-python

I'm trying to uninstall MySQL on OS X 10.10.3 and I found these commands to follow:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
edit /etc/hostconfig and remove the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
```

It seems that `/etc/hostconfig` file doesn't exist.

Did I miss anything? What does this file do and what should I do to ensure MySQL is completely removed?

Comment: What does this have to do with [MySQL-Python](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 11):

As of OS X Yosemite, /etc/hostconfig is no longer installed as part of the OS.

Comment: Why? Replacement?

Comment: @powder366 as far as I can tell the replacement is `ect/hosts`